# Sending a specific variable value for link_to method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

Is there a way to send a specific variable value for link_to method in Rails? In my case I want a variable @result to be 5 instead of 10 when a user presses a link_to button.

```
<%= link_to t('meters'), full_report_path, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' %>

def full
  @result = 10
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to just send params with the link_to , that's it, it will be available in the method.

```
<%= link_to t('meters'), full_report_path(:result => 5), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' %>
```

in your method,

```
def full
  if params[:result].present? 
    @result = params[:result]
  else 
    @result = 10
  end
end
```

You can try by checking whether the method is called from link, by checking whether the params are present, if present 5 else 10. Thats it.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to you can find it here.

Comment: But you deleted that in other cases result should be always 10. Any ideas on how to keep result = 10?